# changing ajax retrieved information with jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code for a weather app and after it shows the temperature in Celsius which is retrieve by ajax from https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?, I want to be able to change it to Fahrenheit with Jquery click but it wont let me:

here is the link to my code in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ashmiricoding18/pen/wyEoZa)

```js
function getW(lat, lon) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?" + lat + "&" + lon,
    success: function(val) {
      $("#city").html(val.name);
      $("#country").html(", " + val.sys.country);
      $("#weather").html(val.weather[0].main);
      $("#wind").html(val.wind.speed + "km/hr");
      $("#temp").html(val.main.temp + " ");
      $("#temp1").html(val.main.temp + " ");

      var a = Math.floor(val.main.temp * 9 / 5 + 32);

      $("#F").click(function() {
        $("#temp1").html(a);
      });




    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center" id="h"> Show the Local Weather</h1>

  <div class="text-center lead">


    <p>
      Location: <strong><span id="city"></span>
         <span id="country"></span> </strong>
      </br>
      Weather: <strong><span id="weather"></span></strong>
      </br>
      Temperture: <strong><span id="temp"></strong>
      </br>
      Temperture: <strong><span id="temp1"></span></strong><button class="btn btn-primary" id="C">&#8451;</button ><button class="btn btn-success" id="F">&#8457;</button>
      </br>
      Wind-speed: <strong><span id="wind"></span></strong>
    </p>


  </div>


  <footer class="text-center">
    <h6 class>Created by <strong>Ash Miri</strong></h6>
  </footer>


</div>
```

Comment: What currently happens?

Comment: I ran your code, its changing for me. Have you given location permission to your site?

Answer (score 0):

there is an error on the following line :

```
$button.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Submitted');
```

`$button` is not defined. Either define it or remove this line. The code work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

When making the request to the API I received the following error message.

```
{"error":"Please provide longitude as lon and latitude as lat as numbers/floats."}
```

Based on this I updated the request url and everything worked fine.

```
https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon
```